# Only return listed column values

Tags: python, pyqgis-3

I have vector data:
[image]

And would like to iterate over the attribute table returning only two field values. Isn't there a way to limit the values returned by `getFeatures` so all attributes does not have to be read? This work but seems convoluted:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
fields_to_return = ['KKOD','KATEGORI']
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    print([feat[f] for f in fields_to_return])

[414, 'Kommun']
[414, 'Kommun']
[414, 'Kommun']
...
```

In ArcGIS I would do:

```
with arcpy.da_SearchCursor(r'C:\data.gdb\ak_riks',fields_to_return) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print(row)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should "very often" use QgsFeatureRequest :

- https://qgis.org/api/classQgsFeatureRequest.html
- https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsFeatureRequest.html

If you need only a subset of attributes, and also maybe you don't need the geometry, you can do something like:

```
expected_fields = ['KKOD', 'KATEGORI']
layer = iface.activeLayer()
indexes = [layer.fields().indexFromName(field) for field in expected_fields]

request = QgsFeatureRequest()
request.setFlags(QgsFeatureRequest.NoGeometry)
request.setSubsetOfAttributes(indexes)
for feature in layer.getFeatures(request):
    print(feature['KKOD'], feature['KATEGORI'])
```

You need to check your attributes index.

I **really** suggest you to read http://nyalldawson.net/2016/10/speeding-up-your-pyqgis-scripts/ This will highly speed up your scripts. Instead to query all attributes, with geometry, just query what you need in your scripts.

Answer (score 7):

From Docs, you can pass a `QgsFeatureRequest` to `getFeatures()`

https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Vector/QgsVectorLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.getFeatures

`QgsFeatureRequest` describe the way you retrieve the `QgsFeature`
You can use `setSubsetOfAttributes` (https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Feature/QgsFeatureRequest.html#qgis.core.QgsFeatureRequest.setSubsetOfAttributes).

The QgsFeatureRequest object that can be pass to `getFeatures()` has a lot of options. There are describe in the docs. For example you can:

- Filter features by an extent
- Filter features by an expression (using `QgsExpression`)
- Avoid fetching geometry to improve performance
- get only a subset of attributes (it's your use case)
- ...

Plus, all options can be chained (e.g., filter by extent and retrieving only some fields without geometry)

See : https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Feature/QgsFeatureRequest.html

You can find some example using this [here](https://python.hotexamples.com/examples/qgis.core/QgsFeatureRequest/setSubsetOfAttributes/python-qgsfeaturerequest-setsubsetofattributes-method-examples.html)

Answer (score 1):

With your help I ended up using a generator like this (for when I forget it):

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
fields_to_return = ['kommunkod','lanskod', 'lansnamn']

indexes = [layer.fields().indexFromName(field) for field in fields_to_return]
request = QgsFeatureRequest()
request.setFlags(QgsFeatureRequest.NoGeometry)
request.setSubsetOfAttributes(indexes)

dataGenerator = ([f[fieldname] for fieldname in fields_to_return] for f in layer.getFeatures(request))

for feats in dataGenerator:
    print(feats)

#[862.0, 8.0, 'Kalmar län']
#[2460.0, 24.0, 'Västerbottens län']
#[643.0, 6.0, 'Jönköpings län']
#...
```